# GNU Mailutils attach file

Tags: email, gnu

Is it possible to attach a file to an email from the CLi using mail?

I am having trouble finding this feature on the manpage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this is generally to use [mutt](http://www.mutt.org) instead:

```
$ mutt -s "test subject" -a test.jpg user@example.com < test.txt
```

mutt is available on most unix-like platforms these days and usually comes installed in the base OS.

Your other option is to uuencode the file and send it through mail:

```
    $ uuencode test.jpg test.jpg | mail user@example.com
```

as explained [here](http://www.shelldorado.com/articles/mailattachments.htm).

Answer (score 1):

can try

```
mail name@mailserver.com -s "Attached file" <<EOF                 
Hi

~| uuencode $HOME/filename.txt filename.txt

EOF
```

atleast with gnus mailutils
see http://mailutils.org/manual/html_section/mail.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're restricted to using "mail", then you can use uuencode to encode the file. I think the modern mail clients still support uunecode :)
uuencode file.jpg file.jpg | mail -s "pic" "me@example.com"
File named is passed twice (first is the local file to be encoded and second is the file name as it will be extracted on the remote system).

Otherwise, you can use mutt or metamail to send MIME encoded mails. You can use both from command line.